# Nested linearLayout doesn't work

Tags: android

I'm having problem drawing a nested linearLayout.
After the second linearLayout (the first included in the main linearLayout), nothing else is shown! But i don 't have any error message in my xml file.

```
---main linearLayout--------------------------------
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" 
    >
------first included linearLayout: it's shown without nay problems--------------------
    <LinearLayout 
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.4"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />   
</LinearLayout>



------second included linearLayout: it's NOT shown--------------------
<LinearLayout 
       android:background="#CCCCCC"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:weightSum="1">


    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
         android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_height="100dp"/>
</LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: this is because your top Linear layout orientation is horizontal. change it to **vertical**

Comment: if you got the solution to your problem then accept the answer as accepted

Comment: @Matteo Depasquali is your problem solved with the given solution?

Answer (score 0):

Change at the top of the layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" 
    >
```

To  this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" 
    >
```

Answer (score 0):

Set this,

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

to your first and second included `linearLayout`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make your top `Linearlayout` orientation `android:orientation="vertical"`.

> ```
> <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
> xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
> android:layout_width="fill_parent"
> android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
> android:orientation="vertical" <---Change orientation.
> tools:context=".MainActivity"
> ```

Comment: Thank to all of. Setting the android:orientation to vertical, it works, but i need a horizontal orientation! is there a way to doit?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, with your help, i found a way to solve the problem.
In the xml file i set the android:orientation to "vertical", and then i make my app "horizontal" with `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);` in my main activity class. Is this the right way to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, with your help, i found a way to solve the problem. In the xml file i set the android:orientation to "vertical", and then i make my app "horizontal" with `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);` in my main activity class. Is this the right way to solve my problem?